# Google Cloud IoT Few config updates mesages are missing when sending config updates frequently from cloud functions to device

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, esp32, google-cloud-iot

I am using config update and cloud functions for communication between mobile application and esp32 device by following the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/iot-device-to-device), but when I am sending config update messages frequently some of them are not sending; say out of 5 only 3 config update messages are going, I have two questions:

1) How frequently we can send config update to avoid some missing updates.
2) Is there any alternative way to communicate between cloud functions and IoT device.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: [[IoT docs](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/config/configuring-devices#limits)]

> Configuration updates are limited to 1 update per second, per device.
>   However, for best results, device configuration should be updated much
>   less often — at most, once every 10 seconds.
>
> The update rate is calculated as the time between the most recent
>   server acknowledgment and the next update request.

If your operations are mostly configuration updates I cannot think another alternative that could perform better.